# Missing word? "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's"

Tags: grammaticality

Consider the following sentence

*Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's.*

When I put it into a few grammar checkers like Grammarly, I get no errors. But I feel that there should be an error - like a word following "else's" (e.g., *"Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life."*, a quote due to Steve Jobs)

Is there some sort of grammar error here, and if so what is it called?

Comment: may I ask, why the down vote? I am new here, have no clue about the norms of this site, and doubt I will return as this is not my area

Comment: It's an "error of idiomacy". The utterance is perfectly grammatical, and easily understood by any native Anglophone. It's just that idiomatically, we only ever speak of *living someone else's **life***, not of *living their **time***.

Comment: Compare: "I had no pizza, so I ate John's."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of semantics, not syntax. Your sentence is equivalent to:

> Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's **time.**

This is perfectly grammatically correct. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The expression “living someone else’s life” is not a psychological term, yet we intuitively understand what it means. Usually, it means that a person does not follow their desires and goals but tries to fulfill a particular average life scenario, “written” for them by other people. More often than not, it is our family’s scenario, although we sometimes use the scenarios that are offered to us by social media, films, and popular culture. <[source](https://medium.com/better-advice/6-signs-that-you-are-living-somebody-elses-life-b31e4a55f72)>

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, there is justification for this sentence.

'Time' is listed as a synonym of 'lifetime' by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time) (sense 5a) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/time) (below; emphasis mine):

> **time** [12] [singular noun]:
>
> Your time is the amount of *time that you have to live*, or to do a
> particular thing.
>
> - The hunt for a solution is on, and time is running out.
> - Every administration has its time. And when your time is over, you leave.
> - **I doubt I would change anything if I had my time again.**

Certainly 'if I had my time to live over again' is part of a well-known expression of regret. It corresponds to the fairly common cognate-object string 'live one's life [again/over]', and these show that the verb 'live' **is** used transitively on at least some occasions, with 'life' or 'time'.

................

However,

- Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's

stretches a rather unusual usage probably beyond acceptable limits. 'Time' in 'Your time is limited' usually refers to the second subsense mentioned in the Collins extract: *the amount of time that you have to do a particular thing*. So we probably have a zeugma, and 'your life' would be better than 'it'.

Or, as you (after Steve Jobs) suggest, adding 'life' after 'someone else's' allows the same meaning of time (*the amount of time you have available*) for both 'time' and 'it' ... probably a neater, crisper solution.